# Making an axios POST request with multipart/form-data, via React Native Debugger

Tags: multipartform-data, axios

I am trying to upload a file from React Native to my server. However I am unable to set the `'Content-Type'` header to `multipart/form-data`.

Here's my simple request:

```
axios({
  uri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  method: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
});
```

I am using the React Native Debugger to monitor Network requests.

When I see my Network request inside the Debugger, I see this:

`'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'`

and the Request Payload is simply `[object Object]`

User Agent:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ReactNativeDebugger/0.7.13 Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Electron/1.7.9 Safari/537.36`

If I am unable to do this with the React Native Debugger, can anyone suggest any steps to testing via Expo.

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 17):

Using the latest version of Axios (0.17.1), you make an HTTP request with `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` in the header as follows:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('action', 'ADD');
formData.append('param', 0);
formData.append('secondParam', 0);
formData.append('file', new Blob(['test payload'], {
  type: 'text/csv',
}));
axios({
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/hello',
  method: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
});
```

Two things: I am using `url`, not `uri`. Also, please insert your own form data and url. Inspecting the request, which has been replied successfully, this is what I get for the request header:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After hours trying to make it work, I realized that a `multipart/form-data` needs a boundary that is generated dynamically depending on the amount of data that is being sent.

Here is the code that works for me:

```js
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('field_name', 'field_pictures');
    data.append('files[file]', fs.createReadStream(filepath), filename);
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': 'here you can set your headers',
        ...data.getHeaders() // this line is the key
        // you need to mix your headers with those generated by the form data
    }
    return axios.post(url, data, { headers });
```

Comment: getHeaders() is not available as method from FormData type

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply:

`axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=someArbitraryUniqueString';`

It will set your headers for sure. However, I have been struggling with form data in React Native for a day and without success. After some experimental aproaches, I found out that everything works **without debugger**. I don't know why but with debugger, I have been sending empty body to the server.

What's more **I didn't need to set headers** as it is your question in this post.

Answer (score 0):

According to @JMA answer,

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export async function somefunction(data) {
    const formData = new FormData(); // No imports needed
    for(let key in userData) {
        formData.append(key.toString(), data[key].toString())
    }
    return axios.post(`${ROUTE}`, formData, {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    });
}
```

where: `data` is your payload to what you want to send. `somefunction` is function that send POST request to `ROUTE`.